# Strange Rails console behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

When I run a multi-line statement in the Rails 3.0.1 console, pressing enter doesn't actually run the statement. Instead, it goes to a new console line, and the cursor has been tabbed to the right. Then I have to run a basic line (like `p "hey"`), and then the multi-line statement will run.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > images = Image.all;images.each do |im|; if im.imagestore_width.blank?;im.save;end;
ruby-1.9.2-p0 >     p "hey"
```

I've been doing it like this for awhile and it's been working okay. But now I've got a problem in the console and it might be related. When I ran the above code, instead of it working like it normally does, it just went to a new console line with a ? added

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > images = Image.all;images.each do |im|; if im.imagestore_width.blank?;im.save;end;
ruby-1.9.2-p0 >     p "hey"
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>
```

When it does this, I can't exit the console

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>  exit
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>  ^C
```

Are these problems related? How can I fix them?

Comment: do a script and launch it with your runner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the line:

```
images = Image.all;images.each do |im|; if im.imagestore_width.blank?;im.save;end;
```

You have an `end` to close the `if` but not an `end` to close the `do` block of the `each`.

This is why the console is redisplaying the prompt asking for more input before executing your statements.

Try:

```
images = Image.all;images.each do |im|; if im.imagestore_width.blank?;im.save;end;end
```

Notice, you will see the same behaviour with brackets. `irb` or `console` won't execute until the brackets balance e.g.

```
irb(main):010:0> (3 *
irb(main):011:1* (2 + 1)
irb(main):012:1> )
=> 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Dunno what's wrong with irb/console but your ruby code could look a lot nicer:

```
images = Image.all.each { |im| im.save if im.imagestore_width.blank? }
```

The general consensus is to use {} rather than do/end for single line blocks in ruby.